# Trying to set incoming SSH IP address in tmux Status Bar

Tags: command-line, unix, tmux

I'm trying to set the incoming IP address of my SSH client in the tmux status bar but for the life of me I can't figure it out. This is my current setting in my .tmux.conf

```
set -g status-right '#[fg=white]#(echo $SSH_CONNECTION | awk '{print $1}')'
```

What gives?

Comment: What about `echo $SSH_CLIENT|cut -d " " -f 1`? Or to stay with your example: `echo $SSH_CONNECTION | awk "{print \$1}"` ...

Comment: The immediate problem with your `status-right` is that you are trying to nest single quotes inside other single quotes. STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED's comment and my answer address that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Bash parameter expansion allows you to remove a suffix from the expansion of a variable using the % operator. A single % sign matches the shortest suffix, %% the longest. Since `SSH_CONNECTION` has 3 space-separated fields, you need to use %% to remove all but the first field (the IP address).

```
${SSH_CONNECTION%% *}  # Remove the first space and everything that follows it.
```

Since the value of `status-right` is processed by `strftime(3)` first, you need to double
the percent signs, as `strftime` will replace %% with a literal %.

```
set -g status-right '#[fg=white]#(echo ${SSH_CONNECTION%%%% *})'
```

Comment: Commands in `#()` will inherit the “global” environment. This means the value shown will be from when the *server* was started. If the OP wants the value provided by the most recent client to attach to the *session*, then they will need to parse the output of `tmux show-env`. Something like `set -g status-right 'foo…#(tmux show-env|grep ^SSH_CONNECTION=|cut -d= -f2|cut -d" " -f1)…bar'` (easier to understand?) or `set -g status-right 'foo…#(tmux show-env|sed -n "/^SSH_CONNECTION=/{s/[^=]*=//;s/ .*//;p;}")…bar'` (fewer processes).

Comment: Very good point, and deserving of its own answer.

Comment: Nothing of this work for me :( What it could be? I tried every other example here - empty bar always.